# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)?

Tags: php, php-7

I am using the overloading in PHP, whats the problem with my PHP code even its only 8 lines of code:

```
class c1{
  public function __call($name,$array){
      if($this->$name()){ return true;}
  }
}

$cl = new c1;
echo $cl->m1();
```

and it says:

"**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)**"

Comment: You attempt to call `m1()`, `__call()` is invoked and tries to call `m1()` `__call()` is invoked and tries to call `m1()` etc... Endless loop.  At least endless until memory is exhausted.

Comment: You might want `if(method_exists($this, $name)){ return true;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making an infinite loop with this code :

`if($this->$name()){ return true;}`

This line makes a call to __call, that makes a call to __call, and so on, because the function "m1" is not defined.

Comment: So you mean that the __call() method is called continuously. Then whats the point behind this ? Why it is called continuously ? I think it is such a strange behavior of PHP. Instead it should call the __call() method once and return the expected result. Why it is called again and again ?

Comment: It never reaches `return` statement. @StressedBrain

Comment: You mean that **__call()** is called for those method which are either not exist or nor accessible so that is why the **if($this->$name()){ return true;}** statement itself calls the **__call()** method which in the result becomes the infinite loop. Is my story correct ? @Tiois

Comment: @StressedBrain: Yes, exactly.  You are specifically calling an undefined function in the `if` which in turn calls `_call()` again.